# How to avoid "Unexpected request: GET" for a call made during app.run cycle without changing all my unit tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

My Angular app has a Factory that fetches logged in user information:

```
.factory('UserInfo', function ($http) {
  return $http.get('/api/v1/whoami');
}
```

This factory is injected as soon as the application finishes bootstrapping.

Before adding this factory all my unit tests were passing but after adding it, all the unit tests that use `$httpBackend` broke with the error message:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/v1/whoami
Expected GET /api/v1/foobar
```

I could add the 2 lines below the comment:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {

  $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
  //these 2 lines fix all unit tests for this "describe"
  $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/v1/whoami').respond({foo: 'bar'});
  $httpBackend.flush();

}));
```

On all unit tests that use `$httpBackend` to make them pass again, or write a mock for my `UserInfo` factory, but I want to be able to test the factory too.

Is there any way to avoid this error without having to write those 2 lines on every `describe` block that uses `$httpBackend`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely do not want to add two lines to every unit test.   If the bootstrapping logic changes (e.g. another API call is added or caches are cleared), you will have to modify every unit test again.

You can move all of your bootstrap-support code (currently 2 lines) into a **setup** function in a **testUtils** service.  Then, when the bootstrap logic changes, you will need to change only one function.  Still, however, you will have brittle tests.  A red test should indicate that something has gone wrong with the unit being tested.  When the bootstrap logic changes and the tests go red, the team will need to scramble to find the root cause of the error and make the necessary updates to **testUtils.setup** (which may be more involved than just an additional **$httpBackend.whenGET**).

The better solution is move all of your components (services, directives, controllers, filters) out of the main (**app**) module. Each module should contain either a single component or several closely coupled components.  Each unit test will then load only the module being tested, bypassing the bootstrap code.  In fact, **karma.conf.js** should not need to load **app.js** at all.  You can count on this approach doubling the speed of your unit tests as well.

As for testing **UserInfo**, move it into its own module and write a unit test for it.

I just led a team making exactly the changes described above.  The effort was less than a day, and our unit tests are now both faster and much more robust.

See [Angular Developer Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) for a discussion on modularity and unit testing.

Comment: I like this idea of separating components into different modules. However it breaks my usual workflow of adding routes, factories, views, etc. via yeoman-generator cli as it assumes you only have 1 module, and I would have to modify the `angular.module(...` line everytime I create a new component. A minor inconvenience for such a promising result.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times there will be things required by the app to get running. Like User authentication, translations etc.

For these cases I usually add these expectations in a beforeEach in each spec.

```
describe('Directive test', function() {
   var $httpBackend;

   beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
       // inject your stuff
       $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpbackend')

       // set up app specific expectations
       $httpBackend.whenGET('/api/account').respond({});
   }))

   afterEach(function() {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
   });

   it('first test', function() {
        // do your tests
   })
})
```

I personally don't see any issues with this approach. There will be some repetition around the tests but think it is ok.

Think at one point you need to acknowledge that when the test starts and you load your module the app is technically being bootstrapped. This will kick off some of your app code. So either deal with these expectations in the test or change your app. Would say handling this in the test is better most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

In this situations your options are:

1. use `$httpBackend.expectGET(...).respond(...)` as you pointed out
2. use [`$provide` to pass a different implementation](http://www.sitepoint.com/mocking-dependencies-angularjs-tests/) when the lookup of `UserInfo` is performed

Now you may end up repeating this in multiple places (depending on your project structure). If that is the case, simply extract the block of code, put it in a separate JS file and include that file in your runner (if you use something like [grunt-contrib-jasmine](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine), add said file to the `vendor` list.)

Comment: I am using grunt and some similar tasks (included with angular yeoman generator) like grunt-karma and karma-jasmine. I like the idea of having that block of code in a separate file, would grunt-contrib-jasmine let me only include it on the tests that use `$httpBackend` except for this factory? I couldn't find that in the readme.

Comment: Think about it this way, if you had one file with this inside:
`beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {

  $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
  //these 2 lines fix all unit tests for this "describe"
  $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/v1/whoami').respond({foo: 'bar'});
  $httpBackend.flush();

}));`
That will run before all of the 'it', which would solve your problem

Comment: I just re-read your comments. I think that if you are already using a plugin that runs your test, stick to it. Just ensure that you include your additional file